# Macro VBA to delete a row only if it doesn't contain the word "keep" in column BR

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I am trying to write a macro on a password protected sheet that will allow users to delete a specific row but only if the cell in column BR does not contain the word "keep" and if they choose a row that cannot be deleted an error message will pop up stating "You have chosen a row that cannot be deleted. Please choose another row".

I have worked out the first part (below) but don't know how to tell it to only delete the row if the word "keep" is not in column BR. I am very new to VBA and muddling along via google but I am officially stuck.

```
Dim x As Integer
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
x = InputBox("Please Enter the Row Number")
Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
Sub not_mentioned()
    Dim x As Long
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    x = InputBox("Please Enter the Row Number")
    If Not UCase(Cells(x, 70)) Like "*KEEP*" Then
        Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
        MsgBox "You have chosen a row that cannot be deleted." & Chr(10) & "Please choose another row"
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
End Sub
```

Comment: Uptick for anticipating needs with `Like`! I almost took it back for not qualifying ;) (half joking)

Comment: Thanks heaps - this has worked :) Can these be changed to delete a range of rows i.e. enter start row and enter finish row but the same checks made if only deleting one row?

Comment: If you need more than one input, you should go for a simple [UserForm](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html). Give it a try and come back here if you struggle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method asking the user to select a cell on the row to delete with `Application.InputBox`.

`Option Compare` text makes this non-case-sensitive. I.E. `KEEP` = `keep`. It's also unclear if the cell will have `Keep` mixed in with a string, or will just contain the word `Keep`. Either way, looks like you have a solution to cover both!

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub DeleteMe()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim TargetRow As Range

On Error Resume Next 'If user hits "Cancel" on Input Box
    Set TargetRow = Application.InputBox("Please Select a Cell on Row to Delete", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not TargetRow Is Nothing Then
    If ws.Cells(TargetRow.Row, "BR") = "keep" Then
        MsgBox "You have chosen a row that cannot be deleted. Please choose another row", vbCritical
    Else
        ws.Unprotect "password"
        ws.Cells(TargetRow.Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        ws.Protect "password"
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help I have got it to work :)